# how to pass a dictionary to another dictionary in python robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

My test case has below line

```
${text_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=First Name  Length=225  encryption_type=LineFPEEngine  Text=dtypeS
${email_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=Email Address  Length=NULL  encryption_type=emailFTEEngine  Text=dtypeE
${phone_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=Mobile Number  Length=NULL  encryption_type=PhoneNumberEncryptionEngine  Text=dtypeH
${custom_fields}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  TextName=${text_field}  Email=${email_field}  Phone=${phone_field}
${field_ids}=  create custom fields  ${custom_fields}
```

but when print type of custom field is

```
<class 'robot.utils.dotdict.DotDict'>
```

Now if try to print 
            for i in custom_fields:
                print i, custom_fields[i]['Text']
it saying TypeError: string indices must be integers
How can i acess this

Comment: The syntax shown is clearly not python, although the output of the class type looks like python's output. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Its a python robot framework

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That means that if you have a python-based keyword, please show it and how you're calling it. The problem doesn't appear to be related to dictionaries since the error metions `string indices`.

Comment: You have created a dictionary but you are trying to loop through it. A dictionary is  different from a list. So you have the choice of looping through the keys or the elements indexed by them. But you can refer to Brian's answer to access items inside a dict by index, assuming that is what you ACTUALLY want.

Answer (score 1):

Robot dictionaries are a subclass of the normal dict. You can use them exactly like a normal dict, but with the added ability to use dot notation when the keys don't have special characters in them (eg: `${custom_fields.TextName}`

The error you say you get mentions a text index not a dictionary index, but without seeing the code that generates the error it's impossible to know what you're doing wrong. When I create a keyword with the following definition, it works fine:

Keyword definition:

```
# example.py
def print_text(custom_fields):
    for i in custom_fields:
        print i, custom_fields[i]['Text']
```

Example test case:

```
# example.robot
*** Settings ***
Library  /tmp/example.py

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${text_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=First Name  Length=225  encryption_type=LineFPEEngine  Text=dtypeS
    ${email_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=Email Address  Length=NULL  encryption_type=emailFTEEngine  Text=dtypeE
    ${phone_field}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  Name=Mobile Number  Length=NULL  encryption_type=PhoneNumberEncryptionEngine  Text=dtypeH
    ${custom_fields}=  CREATE DICTIONARY  TextName=${text_field}  Email=${email_field}  Phone=${phone_field}
    print text  ${custom_fields}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to iterate through a list rather than a dictionary. the syntax for looping through dictionaries is like this

```
# lets say custom_fields = {'TextName': 'test value', 'Email': 'email value'}
custom_fields = {'TextName': 'test value', 'Email': 'email value'}

#loop through the dictionary like this
for item in custom_fields.items():
    print item 

# keep in mind that the items() returns a list of key, value tuple pairs
```

you can check here for a reference on using dictionaries
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like you have a list of keys AND a dict and you want to use the list to loop through the dict.
So what you want to do is,

```
for i in field_ids:
    print custom_fields[i]
```